# Do I need to have a Startup.cs on my Frontend?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, cors

This question is related to this:

The problem I'm having is that I am trying to implement a SignalR with CORS from one ASP.NET (localhost:50000) project called Frontend to another ASP.NET MVC project (in the same solution) (localhost:60000).

When I run the application I get this error message in the console:

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>   - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
>   - No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting
>   owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>   To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the
>   appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or
>   configuration method name in your web.config.

When I add a OWIN Startup class I don't get this error message:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

And I guess it's because it is trying to find the hubs in it's own project.

**Question 1:**
Do I need a startup on my Frontend?

**Question 2 (if Question 1 == yes):**
Must I in the Startup map SignalR to my Backend?

**EDIT:**
index.html:

```
<!--Script references -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:50000/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- HEAD ^^^ -->

<!-- Deleted stuff -->

<!-- BODY  vvv -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var broadcaster = $.connection.loginHub;
            console.log("broadcaster: " + broadcaster)

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            });

        });
    </script>
```

After re-creating my Frontend project and only installing the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS` package I know receive this error in the console:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found .... Requested URL
>   http://localhost:60000/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%5D&_=1443076975867

http://localhost:60000 is the Frontend so I'm not sure why that is the requested URL.

When checking `http://localhost:50000/signalr/hubs` I get a website from `ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.2.0` and also when I print out `broadcaster` in the console it says `broadcaster: [object Object]` so some sort of connection seems to be established.

Comment: In which projects are you using SignalR?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi I installed SignalR in both projects through nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to set up the client to point to your actual hub location since by default it's the current server.

`$.connection.hub.url = '<yourbackendurl>`;

Do that before `connection.hub.start` is called and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your Backend project you need to install these packages:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

And its Startup class should be like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
```

In your Frontend project you need to install this package:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS
```

Also you can install SignalR for .NET client:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
```

Comment: I installed SignalR.JS and it didn't work and after that I installed `SignalR.Client` with no success. This is the error message in the console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I edited my post with some more information.